# android table with more than one column like iOS collectionView

Tags: android, uicollectionview

is there a custom UI element on android that will behave like iOS collection view?
[like a grid view, that is scrollable]
or do I have to make a custom table layout custom cells that behave like columns?

here a shot of a UICollectionView for iOS
[image: uiCollection View]

is there an example for this?

thanks!

Comment: what does the collection view look like?

Comment: Use Gridview and setCollumn = 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the collection view in iOS, but I guess `TableLayout` is what you are looking for.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

In API14+ there is `GridLayout` as well.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: hi, thanks, I need this table yes, but on the cells I need different columns, is this possible with tableLayout? thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "different columns"? I don't understand that.

Comment: hi, please see the screenshots, there are 3 columns , on the first cell: 0 , 1, 2... so this "table" have 3 columns

Comment: Sure, that's why it's called table. There are columns and rows. GridLayout allows you to be more flexible. It just has cells.

Answer (score 8):

Since the previous answer does not reflect performance issues, such as it does not use recycling (which is important for long lists), here is what you are probably looking for:

GridView if your building blocks are all equal in size
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

or ListView (and a lot of custom logic) if your building blocks have different sizes/widths
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 3):

Gridview is best replacement of Collection View of IOS. following URL will solve your problem.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but the Google team have created a widget used in the IO 2014 app that's perfect. It allows for variable column rows and even headers out of the box.

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/CollectionView.java

You'd have to dig through the source for how it's used, but it's really easy and great to use.

Comment: So CollectionView is either a list or a grid depending on the configuration? Is that correct? Do you think it is going to work with cursor adapters?

Comment: I haven't used it with them. What happens is you create an inventory specifying columns, headers, rows etc. Then you pass it an object with callbacks to create those views and bind them as needed.

Comment: In their app, I think I remember them using cursors so take a look and see. I can share my slightly modified version for with you and how to use them if you wish.  @WindRider

Comment: I've found an extracted version: https://github.com/felixWackernagel/Android-CollectionView/
which supports cursors. And what are your modifications?

Comment: Just supports addHeader. Original version doesn't. Actually the sample you found is how it's used in the Google IO app. They used cursors. Personally I don't like them so I stick to my custom data persistence. @WindRider

Comment: It's sad they didn't implement sticky headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65312/discussion-between-windrider-and-frostymarvelous).

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays `RecyclerView` is what you're looking for. `GridView` and others are considered legacy API now. `RecyclerView` is able to handle these type of layouts more efficiently.