# ScrollableView - swiping over images

Tags: android, ios, titanium-alloy

I have a simple app (so far) that contains a ScrollableView (which incorporates horizontal swiping), which contains 12 views representing all the months of the year. Each view contains 28-31 buttons representing the days of each month. When any of the views is currently visible, the buttons representing all the days take up most of the screen. While swiping will work fine when swiping over an empty area of the view, it will NOT swipe when the user begins the swipe over a button. How do I rectify this?

EDIT: I should probably mention that I'm doing this in Titanium Alloy. And I need it to work on both iOS and Android.

Comment: google for onInterceptTouchEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `UIbutton` over a `Scrollview`, then Swipe Gestures don't work.
Try implementing this structure using `UICollectionView`. 
It will be simple to implement these kind of things.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, but in addition to iOS, will it work for Android as well?
Sorry, I should also mention that I'm using Titanium Alloy.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not aware of these development platforms. please go through the following link, that will be helpful to you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649387/android-table-with-more-than-one-column-like-ios-collectionview

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little research, I came across a Titanium Alloy widget called 'ButtonGrid'. This serves exactly my purposes and words for both iOS and Android.

And thanks very much for taking the time to respond.